# Custom Local Sonar Reports Using Maven

Tags: java, bash, maven, sonarqube

Currently I'm running Sonar through these bash commands:

```
mvn clean install
mvn sonar:sonar -Dsonar.jdbc.url=${jdbc_url} -Dsonar.host.url=${sonar_url}
```

These commands produce a "test-output/my-coverage-report" directory containing an HTML site that serves as a report. However the report doesn't contain lines of code information that my Sonar server does.

If I can get the lines of code information in that report then this solution will work, but also is there any way that I can get this data in a more usable form than an HTML site?

Comment: Which version of SonarQube are you using ? SonarQube doesn't generate any HTML report so I guess you've configured your Maven pom.xml file to generate this HTML report in the test-output/my-coverage-report directory ?

Comment: I am using SonarQube 4.3. The report is being generated by JMockit which is a part of Sonar correct? It is running as part of our Sonar suite without any additional setup. @Freddy